# Randomly mix the order of lines in a file

Tags: python

Suppose I have a file containing some lines:

```
line 1 ...
line 2 ...
...
line n ...
```

Is it possible to have another file where the order of the lines will be randomly mixed ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) module is your friend:

```
import random
with open("infile.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
random.shuffle(lines)
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

should do.

Answer (score 1):

1) read the file
2) store each line in a string array
3) shuffle string array
4) write file

I think that is what you're asking for?